# How to convert audio files to mp3 with lower bitrate and mono channel using map

Tags: ffmpeg

I have wav audio files that have stereo channels. I have to convert them to mp3 with mono channel and 64k bit rate.

For individual file, I can simply do

```
ffmpeg -i input1.wav -ac 1 -ar 44100 -b:a 64k output1.mp3
```

But I have to batch convert files. One simple way is to create a bash script that passes input files to `ffmpeg` one by one.

I need to do batch conversion using `map` feature.

```
ffmpeg -i input1.wav -i input2.wav -map 0:0 output1.mp3 -map 1:0 output2.mp3
```

This too works fine. But it does not let me specify `-ac 1 -ar 44100 -b:a 64k`. If I do

```
ffmpeg -i input1.wav -i input2.wav -ac 1 -ar 44100 -b:a 64k ...
```

Then only first file `input1.wav` gets mono channel and 64k bit rate. Subsequent files stay stereo.

How do I tell `ffmpeg` to use `-ac 1 -ar 44100 -b:a 64k` for the audio streams when using `map` option?

Answer (score 0):

I tried following format and it worked

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -ac 1 -ar 44100 -b:a 64k -map 0 output1.mp3 -ac 1 -ar 44100 -b:a 64k -map 1 output1.mp3
```